# Resizing Microsoft Ads

Tags: c#, uwp, ads

Hi I use Microsofts Ads in my UWP app and I want the ads to resize after the with of the app but cant get it to work.
I understand the ad control must be on of the valid sizes (as described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf1dfe28-9f45-44f8-9bad-81c8b755b62c/support-for-320-x-50-banner-ad-size-in-uwp-apps-with-microsoft-advertising?forum=aiasdk)) so I wrote this code to resize the ad:

```
private void panel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewSize.Width >= 728)
    {
        ad.Width = 728;
        ad.Height = 90;
    }
    else if (e.NewSize.Width >= 640)
    {
        ad.Width = 640;
        ad.Height = 100;
    }
    else if (e.NewSize.Width >= 480)
    {
        ad.Width = 480;
        ad.Height = 80;
    }
    else if (e.NewSize.Width >= 320)
    {
        ad.Width = 320;
        ad.Height = 50;
    }
    else if (e.NewSize.Width >= 300)
    {
        ad.Width = 300;
        ad.Height = 50;
    }
}
```

This made the control resize accordingly but the ad inside the control looked terrible. I added ad.Refresh(); at the end but that didn't change a thing.

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced your same problem.
Unfortunately, the Ads are loaded every 30 seconds and you can not refresh them more then once in 30 seconds. 
This is the reason because the call to the Refresh() method fails.
I used a workaround that I hope it can help you.
I have "covered" the Ad with a StackPanel of the same size (and position) of the Ad. I have showed this panel when I had to change the size of the Ad.
At the refresh of the Ad (you can intercept it by the callback AdRefreshed), I have hidden the cover panel.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="AdsCover" Width="300" Height="50" Visibility="Visible"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.ZIndex="12" Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <Border x:Name="AdsBorder" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="50">
                <TextBlock x:Name="AdsLoading" Text="Ads Loading..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24"
                       TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <UI:AdControl x:Name="adsMS" 
                ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                AdUnitId="10865270"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="50"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Width="300"
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Canvas.ZIndex="10"
                ErrorOccurred="OnAdErrorOccurred"
                AdRefreshed="OnAdRefreshed"/>
```

In the code behind, where you have to change the Ad size, you can do this:

```
    ...
    // Change the size of the Ad. adsW and adsH are the new size
    adsMS->SetValue(WidthProperty, 1.0*adsW);
    adsMS->SetValue(HeightProperty, 1.0*adsH);
    // Cover panel with the same size
    AdsCover->SetValue(WidthProperty, 1.0*adsW);
    AdsCover->SetValue(HeightProperty, 1.0*adsH);
    AdsBorder->SetValue(HeightProperty, 1.0*adsH);

    // If the size are changed, I hide the Ad with the panel.
    // In this way, I can avoid to see the deformed Ad.
    // m_previousAdsWidth and m_previousAdsHeight are the previous size
    // of the Ad.
    if ((m_previousAdsWidth != adsW || m_previousAdsHeight != adsH)
        && m_previousAdsWidth > 0 && m_previousAdsHeight > 0)
    {
        AdsCover->SetValue(VisibilityProperty, Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible);
    }
    m_previousAdsWidth = adsW;
    m_previousAdsHeight = adsH;
    ...
```

In the callback OnAdRefreshed() you can hide the panel

```
// Called when the Ad is refreshed.
void DirectXPage::OnAdRefreshed(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    // If the Ad is hidden by the cover panel, I will make it visible again.
    if (AdsCover->Visibility == Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible)
        AdsCover->SetValue(VisibilityProperty, Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed);
}
```